# how to solve "NameError: name 'indices' is not defined"?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to create a stock prediction but I always get an error in feature scalling

```
# Feature Scaling
sc = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
training_set_scaled = sc.fit_transform(training_set)

# Creating a data structure with 60 time-steps and 1 output
X_train = []
y_train = []
for i in range(60, 2796):
  X_train.append(training_set_scaled[i-60:i, 0])
  y_train.append(training_set_scaled[i, 0])
X_train, y_train = np.array(X_train), np.array(y_train) #error highlighted

X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], X_train[1], 1))
```

For the first error i get this

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

but when I add the "indices" at the codes like this

```
X_train, y_train = np.array(X_train)[indices.astype(int)], np.array(y_train)[indices.astype(int)]
```

the error appear like this

```
NameError: name 'indices' is not defined
```

what should I do to solve this?

Comment: What is this `indices` supposed to be or do?  How is that related to the original error?

Comment: In your own words, when you write `indices.astype(int)`, what do you expect that to mean? When you read an error message that says `NameError: name 'indices' is not defined`, what do you think that means? Do you see how it corresponds to the code? What do you expect the overall code `np.array(X_train)[indices.astype(int)]` to do, and how does that relate to the previous try of `np.array(X_train)`?

Comment: Show the full error for the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because the variable `indices` has not been defined.

You are probably missing code like:

```
       indices = np.array()
```

Once indices is defined you can use it